# Converting image sequence to stereo H.264 video

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, 3d, stereo

I have an image sequence of JPG files exported from Blender. I would like to create a stereo side-by-side (left/right) H.264 video using ffmpeg using libx264.

My image sequence is as follows:

```
image_00001_L.jpg
image_00001_R.jpg
image_00002_L.jpg
image_00002_R.jpg
etc.
```

Here is my current command:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i "image_%05d_L.jpg" -i "image_%05d_R.jpg" -vcodec libx264 -crf 15 -preset veryslow -vf "stereo3d=al:sbsl" vid.mp4
```

According to the [help page](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#stereo3d) for creating stereo videos using ffmpeg there are multiple input image formats supported. I have tried al, abl and sbsl but none seem to produce anything useful (unplayable by VLC or just a regular video). Output format I am using "sbsl" (side by side parallel - left eye left, right eye right).

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stereo3d filter is designed to act upon a single video stream where sequences for both eyes are already present and interleaved in some manner - the filter then changes the arrangement scheme. What you have here is two separate streams which need to be combined.

Assuuming both sequences have the same video properties (resolution, duration..), use

```
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i "image_%05d_L.jpg" -framerate 60 -i "image_%05d_R.jpg" -filter_complex "hstack,format=yuv420p" -c:v libx264 -crf 15 -preset veryslow vid.mp4
```

Comment: This produces a "deprecated pixel format" warning because of yuv420p as well as "DPB size (16 frames > 1011840) > level limit (11 frames, 696320)" warning. The result is a video which is unplayable in VLC/QuickTime. I removed the pixel format "yuv420p" but still got the DPB warning and an unplayable video.

Comment: What resolution are your images? Video should be playable with ffplay. But if the # of samples limit is breached, then players which are a stickler for compliant streams will refuse to play. You can start by adding `-refs 8`.

Comment: Keep the format and ignore the pixel format message. JPEG sources has a different color range than videos. You can add `-color_range 2` to make sure the actual range is correctly signaled.

Comment: Ah thanks, the resolution was too high for H.264 (4214x1920)! I batch resized the images to 4096x1920 and now it renders a proper functioning side-by-side.

Comment: You can do the resize within ffmpeg :)

Comment: Wish I would have known before I opened up IrfanView and converted 4 times before I got the right settings! Is there anything ffmpeg can't do?

Comment: A few things. It tries to be jack-of-all-trades as far as manipulating and converting video and audio data.